# Linking OpenCV3.0.0 statically causes socket to not open GCC5.2 C++11

Tags: c++, sockets, opencv, c++11, g++

I am working on a machine vision project that Analyses live video and sends data to another server. I have the OpenCV portion working on it's own and I have a socket example working on it's own.
When I went ahead to integrate the two, the initial socket call returns -1.

I have narrowed it down to the following example.

I can compile it on it's own and it works fine, Socket opened as expected.
If I link the OpenCV libs, it returns a -1 and cannot open the socket.

I have seen this issue in G++ 5.2.0 on OSX as well as Cygwin. The OSX10.10 built in compiler does however work without issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        cerr << "Error opening socket" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Socket opened" << endl;
}
```

I am using CMAKE to find the packages and link them if that helps.

Comment: Appears like building OpenCV as a shared library and linking it dynamically does "resolve" this issue as a workaround however the original problem still stands.